# Repeating an inline svg pattern

Tags: svg, repeat

How is this done?

Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/p1rwuzf8/1/

This pattern svg when repeated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lEmf.png

Should look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oistX.png

```
svg {
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

<svg width="42" height="44" viewBox="0 0 42 44" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="Page-1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="brick-wall" fill="#000"><path d="M0 0h42v44H0V0zm1 1h40v20H1V1zM0 23h20v20H0V23zm22 0h20v20H22V23z"/></g></g>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing this would be using the image as background-image. For this you would need first to encode the svg image, for example using this tool: [SVG encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

```css
div{width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='42' height='44' viewBox='0 0 42 44' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg id='Page-1' fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg id='brick-wall' fill='%23000'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h42v44H0V0zm1 1h40v20H1V1zM0 23h20v20H0V23zm22 0h20v20H22V23z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

An other way of doing it would be using SVG patterns. For this you need to take the group used to draw the "brick" and use it in a pattern like so:

```html
<svg width="200" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 300">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="brick"  width='42' height='44' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'> >
      <g id="Page-1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="brick-wall" fill="#000"><path d="M0 0h42v44H0V0zm1 1h40v20H1V1zM0 23h20v20H0V23zm22 0h20v20H22V23z"/></g></g>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#brick)"></rect>
</svg>
```